# google.maps.Geocoder.geocode not always returns Australian postcode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm using the google.maps.Geocoder class to resolve Australian addresses entered into a free form input field:

1. pass the entered address (such as "Parramatta") in the google.maps.GeocoderRequest.address field,
2. call google.maps.Geocoder.geocode
3. and then show all returned google.maps.GeocoderResult.formatted_address fields to the user so they can select one.

Problem is that the returned formatted_address fields not always contains the postcode.

```
Pass "Parramatta" into google.maps.GeocoderRequest.address -> 
    receive formatted_address "Parramatta NSW, Australia"

Pass "Strathfield" into google.maps.GeocoderRequest.address -> 
    receive formatted_address "Strathfield NSW 2135, Australia"
```

Looks to me like this is a fault in Google's database, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to resolve addresses that always gives you the postcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [reverse geocode](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Parramatta&addr2=-33.8151285,%20151.0031549&geocode=2) the location returned for Parramatta, it does contain a post code:

```
{
  "long_name": "2150",
  "short_name": "2150",
  "types": [
    "postal_code"
  ]
}
```

That is correct according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parramatta)